# School & class blogs: Categorize with categories or custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

A school is using WP as the presentation frontend. Posts are created to publish news (category news), articles (category articles) and featured content (cat. featured).

The school would like to use WP also to create a school blog and classes blogs.

I was wondering if it would be better to use ordinary posts along with categories (school, classX, classY, classZ) or generate custom post types for this usage.

The first solution would be better because all posts are packed in a unique location, but over time it may get complicated to manage when content grows. Users (kids) may get confused by other posts in the same container.

The second solution would keep separated the two worlds also simplifying user access to the dashboard (using a third party plugin to hide content in the dashboard, showing only sections related to custom posts)

What do you think? Pros and cons?

Comment: I recommand you to set each class as "author". then they will only see there own posts and not others posts

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can you clarify?

Comment: I speak about the author role, read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Summary_of_Roles